# Issue in merging different text on a background image, as multiple pages in PDF, in Python.[Python][PyPDF2][Reportlab]

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab, pypdf

```
page = existing_pdf.getPage(0)
page.mergePage(new_pdf.getPage(0))
output.addPage(page)
page = existing_pdf.getPage(0)
page.mergePage(new_pdf.getPage(1))
output.addPage(page)
```

Here The existing_pdf is the background image in pdf format, which will be merged on different 
PDF consisting of only text.

My goal is to have one large pdf consisting of multiple pages with same background, but with a different text.

A classic example would be a form in which the format(background) is given, and the details are then filled on that format(background) for different users.

I have used IOBuffer as temporary PDF.
My full code is below

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import io
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter,A4

h,w = A4

existing_pdf = PdfFileReader(open("design.pdf", "rb"))

packet = io.BytesIO()
# create a new PDF with Reportlab
can = canvas.Canvas(packet, pagesize=A4)

#Itreative section

can.drawString(0,0, "Hello world")
can.showPage()
can.drawString(0,0, "Neel Mishra")

#Itreative portion ends

can.save()

#move to the beginning of the StringIO buffer
packet.seek(0)
new_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)
# read your existing PDF

output = PdfFileWriter()
# add the "watermark" (which is the new pdf) on the existing page

for page in new_pdf.pages:
    print('Hello')

page = existing_pdf.getPage(0)
page.mergePage(new_pdf.getPage(0))
output.addPage(page)
page = existing_pdf.getPage(0)
page.mergePage(new_pdf.getPage(1))
output.addPage(page)
# finally, write "output" to a real file
outputStream = open("destination.pdf", "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

However whenever I run the code I get one issue; that is the text's get overlapped and the overlapped results are then duplicated. You can run the code.

Requirements are :
Reportlab
PyPDF2
Python 3.6

I am a newbie, so please help me with stack community, I have tried my best to frame my question; however if you find some faults please suggest edits, before down voting the question.

Thank you.